# Android: Saving an ArrayList to SharedPreferences, but loading it is not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save, sharedpreferences

After asking a similar question this morning, I did more research and found (I think) a way to save/load my ArrayList by saving it to SharedPreferences (After converting it to a Json String).

The problem is, I don't know where to put my saveListe() and my loadListe().

I don't get any error, but when restarting the application, the list is still the default one (It has 1 game in it).

Those 2 methods and my list are in a ListeJeux Class.

I tried using loadListe() in my mainActivity, and I used saveListe() in another activity (that add a game to the list for test purposes) just after adding a game.

If I launch the other activity, it adds a game to the list (this part is working), but if I restart the application, the list still contains 1 game only (default). What is the problem?

ListeJeux (contains save and load methods + the default list):

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ListeJeux extends ActionBarActivity {
    // By default, the list contains one game, if the listView show more than
    // one, then addJeu() works, if it still shows more than one game after a
    // restart, then the save/load works (not working for now).
    static Jeu jeu1 = new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur");
    static ArrayList<Jeu> jeux = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jeu1));

    // This is only to test.
    static void addJeu() {
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur"));
    }

    // Takes "jeux" (this is where the problem happens, I think), and makes it a
    // Json String. Then store it in SharedPreference.
    static public void saveListe(Context context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String listeJson = gson.toJson(jeux);
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("listePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("listeEditor", listeJson);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // Takes the contain of the SharedPreference (Json String) and reverts it to
    // an ArrayList. Then returns it.
    static public ArrayList<Jeu> loadListe(Context context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("listePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String extractedJson = prefs.getString("listeEditor", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Jeu>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<Jeu> jeux = gson.fromJson(extractedJson, type);
        return jeux;
    }
}
```

The MainActivity (in which I use the loadList() method):

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        ListeJeux.loadListe(this);
        setupTrouvezButton();
        setupRechercherButton();
        setupListeButton();     
    }

    private void setupListeButton() {
        Button listeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainListe);
        listeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListeActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    private void setupTrouvezButton() {
        Button trouvezButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainTrouvez);
        trouvezButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrouvezActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupRechercherButton() {
        Button rechercherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMainRechercher);
        rechercherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RechercherActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the other activity (that add a game to the list then save it):

```
    package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class RechercherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rechercher);
        ListeJeux.addJeu();
        ListeJeux.saveListe(this);
        setupRetourButton();
    }

    private void setupRetourButton() {
        Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRechercherRetour);

        retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rechercher, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a arraylist to the shared prefrence, you have to serialize the arraylist before you saving. I would prefer saving a serialized object to the sdcard instead of saving it to the shared prefrence, if it is not a confidantial information. if it is a cache file, i would recomend you save it to the app cache directory.

Serialize an object

```
public class SomeClassName implements Serializable{
    private ArrayList<SomeObject> arrayList;

    public void setObject(ArrayList<SomeObject> list){
        arrayList = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<SomeObject> getObject(){
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity although it is deprecated, it extends Activity, so you should be able to override onCreate, onResume and onPause to call your methods to load and save.  For example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rechercher);


    setupRetourButton();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    ArrayList<Jeu> loaded = ListeJeux.loadListe(this);
    for (Jeu j: loaded)
    {
        // This method to add doesn't exist and this whole loop should
        // be refactored into the loadListe method.
        ListeJeux.addJue(j)
    }

    // This size() method doesn't exist either and could also be subsumed into loadList
    if (ListeJeux.size() == 0)
    {
        ListeJeux.addJeu();
        ListeJeux.saveListe(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // Save the list as the app may stop any time after a pause.
    ListeJeux.saveListe(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Personally, I would refactor the code a little so the save and load methods on the list (ListeJeux), actually update the internal list.  As you can see from the diagram at the top of this [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), you really only need to load in onResume as it should always be called before the Activity is displayed.

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm trying to figure out where to put those methods, and I'm also not sure what you mean with those comments in the onResume() method: Why using a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: Put the methods in the ActionBarActivity called MainActivity.  I am assuming you will write the non-existent methods because ListeJeux wraps an array list, so this is to access that internal ArrayList